# HttpPost request in android giving failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: java, android, http-post, android-gallery

I am trying to send an image to a sever in android through httpPost. The image is got from the gallery.
Given below the full code of the activity.

```
    package com.example.faceeventapp;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.Reader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HeaderElement;
    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.ParseException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class TestServerActivity extends Activity {

    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    }
    public void upload(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode!=RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("xxxxxx");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", picturePath));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));

            try {
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                for(int index=0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) {
                    if(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
                        // If the key equals to "image", we use FileBody to transfer the data
                        entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new FileBody(new File (nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue())));
                    } else {
                        // Normal string data
                        entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()));
                    }
                }

                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your photo has been uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }
    public void register(View view) throws InterruptedException
    {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have been registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.signup, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void finish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.finish();
    }
}
```

If I comment the below code it works, since no request is being sent

```
 httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
```

else LogCat says

```
RunTimeException "Failure delivering   ResultInfo{who=null,request=1,result=-1,data=Intent{dat=content://media......}
```

I do not why this is causing a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: You will probably need to check what the server says. As you have not set any encoding I would start to check if the server receives the correct one i.e. multipart/form-data

Comment: @Carsten : It does not reach the server. The app stop working. I have checked the server log also.

Comment: Do you have android.permission.INTERNET in your manifest?